# Automatic forwarding after registration with parse

Tags: ios, view, registration, parse-platform

I have a problem when I register on the screen to registration my app. He carries the data while in parse.com. Only I will not be forwarded to the app, how can I solve that? When I press on to re-register the name already taken.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question? It's unclear exactly what your problem is. Are you using Parse's `PFSignUpViewController`?

Comment: Yes, I use "PFSignUpViewController".

Comment: Kindly add more details if you want others to help you out.

Comment: Here is my "PFSignUpViewController" code:

http://pastebin.com/YGdtJyQt

Comment: I hope someone can help me. Have all the details or code already attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate methods of `PFSignUpViewController`, and perform some action once registration is complete. Usually, if the sign up viewcontroller is displayed modally, this will involve dismissing it.

For example:

```
// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is signed up.
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // Dismiss the PFSignUpViewController
}
```

This [example project](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views) from Parse has a good demo of how to implement a sign up / log in process.